# how to do check column values is not clash if all value correspond to same value of other column, if clashed then return that row

Tags: python, pandas

```
s_id    PSC
pbx     4
pbx     5
pbx     7
pby     8
pbn     8
pby     7
pbn     8
```

now check PSC of pbx does not clash bt PSC of pbn clashed

Answer (score 0):

If `clashed` means there are unique values per groups by `s_id` use:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.groupby('s_id')['PSC'].transform('nunique').ne(1), 
                     'not clash',
                     'clashed')

print (df)
  s_id  PSC        new
0  pbx    4  not clash
1  pbx    5  not clash
2  pbx    7  not clash
3  pby    8  not clash
4  pbn    8    clashed
5  pby    7  not clash
6  pbn    8    clashed
```

Answer (score 0):

clashed if all values in s_id groups are the same (duplicated):

```
df['clash'] = df.duplicated(['s_id', 'PSC'], keep=False)\
                .groupby(df['s_id'])\
                .transform('all')\
                .map({True: 'clashed', False: 'not clashed'})
print(df)

  s_id  PSC        clash
0  pbx    4  not clashed
1  pbx    5  not clashed
2  pbx    7  not clashed
3  pby    8  not clashed
4  pbn    8      clashed
5  pby    7  not clashed
6  pbn    8      clashed
```

Comment: any other answer plz by using for loop, check al values one by one  and if clashed then give in output